# Determine if a matrix can be transformed to a nonnegative matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

Non-negative matrices come up in relation to the Perron-Frobenius theorem.  The definition of a nonnegative matrix is that all of the matrix elements are greater than or equal to zero.  From this, the Perron-Frobenius theorem gives information about the eigenvalues of the matrix.

However, having all positive matrix elements is not a basis-independent statement.  Simply switching a basis vector $\mathbf{e}_i\rightarrow -\mathbf{e}_i$ flips the sign of all the matrix elements in the $i$ column and row (except the diagonal).  So I was wondering if there is a more basis-independent definition of a nonnegative matrix, from which I could immediately infer that a basis exists where the matrix elements are positive, and also that I can immediately apply the Perron-Frobenius theorem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A better way to think about (generalizations of) positive matrices (and nonnegative matrices in general) is that they leave the cone of positive vectors invariant, i.e., if $K := \{ x \in \mathbb{R}^n \mid x >0 \}$, then $AK \subseteq K$.

This is the viewpoint adopted in the book by *[Nonnegative Matrices in the Mathematical Sciences](http://epubs.siam.org/doi/book/10.1137/1.9781611971262)*:
[image]

Comment: Thanks, this looks like the property I was looking for.  Just to clarify, in this passage $\pi(K)$ is the set of matrices leaving the cone $K$ invariant?  Also, is theorem (3.2) supposed to be thought of as a generalization of the Perron-Frobenius theorem?

Comment: The answer is ‘yes’ to both questions.

Answer (score 4):

There exist NS conditions so that $A$ is similar to a $>0$ matrix cf. http://ac.els-cdn.com/0024379571900152/1-s2.0-0024379571900152-main.pdf?_tid=7fe8a7aa-fb62-11e5-be8a-00000aab0f01&acdnat=1459883797_ac85ff1bca4931ef3b847c19555fc6ec

Unfortunately, to use this result, you must prove that $\rho(A)$ is an eigenvalue of $A$ and that the other eigenvalues have a smaller modulus than $\rho(A)$. Conclusion: no interest for you.